# How do I create an integer input stream in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I need to do an assignment where I have to write a while loop with a condition like:

### while (not end of stream) {

}

I'm confused about the "not end of stream part". How do I make it so it stop reading when there is no integer input in the console? It will be entered like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
I am using the Scanner class my code is something like this:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int inputValue = userInput.nextInt();
while(not end of stream) {
   if (.......) {
      ....
   } else {
      ....
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So if you're using nextInt(), I what I'm getting is that the user on the console will enter one int at a time? You just give the console user some escape command instruction at the beginning like "Enter 'q' to quit" and they'll do so, you read it, then end, that's how to know the end. You can't really just know when they're done typing without some prompt (even if it's a timer, something still needs to be in place to read that they're done inputting stuff).

Comment: Not sure why you have two scanners but I assumed `myScanner` is typo and instead should be `userInput`

Comment: How do I make it so it stops after pressing CTRL-D (unix) or CTRL-Z (DOS)? I am getting an infinite loop right now, and looking at some examples with strings I see something like: System.in.read() as well but that doesn't work with integers I guess. After entering a sequence like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7, I need it to somehow go into the while loop one at a time for comparison, and increment a bunch of counters.

Yes that was a typo, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the word *stream* confuse you, when reading from System.in, there is no continuous 'flow' of numbers coming.. The user can type what ever he wants to and as long as he wants to. Until he hits 'Enter' nothing will happen.

That said, the scenario is more like this:

**1** user types `71 2 30 5 1` and hits *Enter*

**2** `userInput.nextInt();` will return the first int it finds so here `71`

**3** now you could do something like this: **[EDITED]**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(">");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputValue = userInput.nextInt();
    while (userInput.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("you just wrote: " + userInput.nextInt());
    }
    userInput.close();
}
```

So until the scanner doesn't find any input that is not an `int` the loop will continue. In other words, when the user types for example an 'b' the loop terminates.

Now it all depends on what you have to do in your `while-loop`. You could test for `userInput.hasNext()` to see if *anything* comes, or `userInput.nextLine()` which will wait for an `Enter` .. or what ever you need.

When I run the above main and type in:[ **1** *Enter* **2** *Enter* **3** *Enter* **4** *Enter* **a** *Enter* ], this is the output:

```
>1                  // <-- this is the number before the while loop
2                   // <-- now another number
you just wrote: 2   // <-- and the while loop makes its first iteration
3                   // <-- then it waits for you to input the 3rd number
you just wrote: 3   // <-- to make its next iteration
4                   // <-- and the 4th
you just wrote: 4   // <-- 4th iteration
a                   // <-- until you type something else

// end of program
```

The user **always** has to hit *Enter* – otherwise the operation system won't give the typed input to the Java program. This has to do with the settings of the Shell / Console that your operation system provides for the Java program to run. So, Java won't see anything of the input until you hit enter.

Comment: I tried this code and when I press a non integer like "enter", it doesn't display anything and goes to a new line. Also doesn't terminate the program and keeps running without doing anything.

Comment: @vikes011: I just copied the complete method and added an example output. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks!! That helped, my code is running now and I just need to work on the program. I was stuck on this part for so long I was going crazy. Just out of curiosity, is it not possible to input a sequence of numbers with spaces like "1 2 3 4 5 6"? Is "enter" a must?

Comment: yes you can enter a whole sequence at once. The 'enter' will just give the sequence to your java program. And this will read the sequence one by one (for each number separated by whitespace it will iterate one time through your while loop). You can even enter 5 (or more) numbers at the beginning, it then will swallow the first and for the remaining 4 numbers it will loop through while..